# Query on one of attributes of composite key in database

Tags: database, composite-key

A composite key contains two columns: col1, and col2. If I run a query on only col1, will the index be used? and why

I guess not, because typically index is implemented as B+ tree. And in B+ tree, keys are stored in interior blocks and all records are stored at the lowest level of the tree. It may be not efficient or impossible if we do the query from the index.

Comment: In the absence of a crystal ball, you're going to have to tell us which database software you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, databases are capable of using the leading column(s) of a composite index.
Whether or not the index actualy **will** be used, is up to the database optimizer to decide.